# Another jQuery EasyUI Combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

Unfortunately I can't get even the most basic function of the EasyUI combobox to work.  I'm trying to populate the combobox options from a PHP/MySQL query.  The query is firing and returning a JSON data object but I can't get the data to appear in the combobox.  The next step will be to pull the rest of the DB content based on the combobox selection but I can even get the combobox to populate at this point.

Here is the JSON data that is returned by the PHP script.

```
{"temps":[{"temp_key":"1","temp_name":"Sorry we missed you"},{"temp_key":"2","temp_name":"Our conversation"}]}
```

Now here is the HTML portion of page that creates the combobox.

```
<div>
            <label for="email_temp">Please select e-mail template:</label>
            <input id="template" class="easyui-combobox" name="email_temp" 
                    data-options="valueField:'temps.temp_key',textField:'temps.temp_content',url:'get_templates.php'">
            </div>
```

I have tried using the valueField and textField options both with and without the "temps" portion of the JSON data object.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your JSON.

In the Combo Box demo it's returned an array directly:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"Java","desc":"Write once, run anywhere"},{"id":2,"text":"C#","desc":"One of the programming languages designed for the Common Language Infrastructure"},{"id":3,"text":"Ruby","selected":true,"desc":"A dynamic, reflective, general-purpose object-oriented programming language"},{"id":4,"text":"Perl","desc":"A high-level, general-purpose, interpreted, dynamic programming language"},{"id":5,"text":"Basic","desc":"A family of general-purpose, high-level programming languages"}]
```

So if you make yours return the array only, it should work:

```
[{"temp_key":"1","temp_name":"Sorry we missed you"},{"temp_key":"2","temp_name":"Our conversation"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct format data that you return to combobox,
combobox needs data looks like

```js
[{
  id:1,
  name:'Jime'
},
{
  id:2,
  name:'Mark'
}]
```